# JavaScript Expanding Divs not working Correctly for me

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/alachgar/upezxLas/3/

Hello All, 
My Javascript that was working fine earlier now is Broken.. it worked for me just yesterday.. now it is the HOUSING Section Part works fine... 
However Starting the Second Section in Light Blue it's Broken... I am not sure what I am missing..!
Please help. Thanks a alot.
Ed-

```
   <script>
    function showRent (rent_box) 
        { 
            var rent_chboxs = 
document.querySelectorAll('[name="rent_eval1"], 
[name="rent_eval2"], 
    [name="rent_eval3"],[name="rent_eval4"],[name="rent_eval5"], 
[name="own_concerns"], 
    [name="address_different"]'); 
            var vis = "none";
            for(var i=0;i<rent_chboxs.length;i++) { 
                if(rent_chboxs[i].checked){
                 vis = "block";
                    break;
                }
            }
    document.getElementById(rent_box).style.display = vis;          
        }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the onclick Event name from **showOwn** to **showRent** in from line 78 to line 90 in your HTMl file

Answer (score 0):

'showOwn' is not defined.
Or change it to showRent may work.